# MySQL LIKE query and relevance result

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table which has 5 fields.

Three main fields are

=> Content 1

=> Content 2

=> Content 3

Content 1 and 2 are html and plain text contents respectively, content 3 has comma separated tags.

I want to provide a search feature that should search these three fields and to output the result ordered by relevance.

I am a newbie to mysql LIKE syntax. Please someone help and teach me.

Comment: please provide some sample data

Comment: it's quite simple.

Content 1 can have '<div class="a-class"><span id="a-id"><h1>Title</h1>Any size of text</span></div>'

Content 2 can have 'Any size of text but not more than 250 chars'

Content 3 can have 'any, size of, text, title, 250 chars'

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE  
   `Content 1` like '%$query%' 
   OR `Content 2` like '%$query%'
   OR `Content 3` like '%$query%'
```

But this query is not working for content 1 which has html element inside the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping. But actually I want to get the result ordered by relevance. Can you help me to achieve that.

Comment: Actually i don't know can do it in MySQL. Because MySQL how to know your relevance.

Comment: Hmmmm, I guess there would be some trick to do that. Don't you think so :(